# How to add a variable of a method of a class in aonther program in python?

Tags: python, ns-3, mininet

I have a class called WIFISegment as below in ns3.py :

```
class WIFISegment( object ):
    """Equivalent of radio WiFi channel.
       Only Ap and WDS devices support SendFrom()."""
    def __init__( self ):
        # Helpers instantiation.
        self.channelhelper = ns.wifi.YansWifiChannelHelper.Default()
        self.phyhelper = ns.wifi.YansWifiPhyHelper.Default()
        self.wifihelper = ns.wifi.WifiHelper.Default()
        self.machelper = ns.wifi.NqosWifiMacHelper.Default()
        # Setting channel to phyhelper.
        self.channel = self.channelhelper.Create()
        self.phyhelper.SetChannel( self.channel )

    def add( self, node, port=None, intfName=None, mode=None ):
        """Connect Mininet node to the segment.
           Will create WifiNetDevice with Mac type specified in
           the MacHelper (default: AdhocWifiMac).
           node: Mininet node
           port: node port number (optional)
           intfName: node tap interface name (optional)
           mode: TapBridge mode (UseLocal or UseBridge) (optional)"""
        # Check if this Mininet node has assigned an underlying ns-3 node.
        if hasattr( node, 'nsNode' ) and node.nsNode is not None:
            # If it is assigned, go ahead.
            pass
        else:
            # If not, create new ns-3 node and assign it to this Mininet node.
            node.nsNode = ns.network.Node()
            allNodes.append( node )
        # Install new device to the ns-3 node, using provided helpers.
        device = self.wifihelper.Install( self.phyhelper, self.machelper, node.nsNode ).Get( 0 )
        mobilityhelper = ns.mobility.MobilityHelper()
        # Install mobility object to the ns-3 node.
        mobilityhelper.Install( node.nsNode )
        # If port number is not specified...
        if port is None:
            # ...obtain it automatically.
            port = node.newPort()
        # If interface name is not specified...
        if intfName is None:
            # ...obtain it automatically.
            intfName = Link.intfName( node, port ) # classmethod
        # In the specified Mininet node, create TBIntf bridged with the 'device'.
        tb = TBIntf( intfName, node, port, node.nsNode, device, mode )
        return tb
```

This class has a method called   **def add( self, node, port=None, intfName=None, mode=None )**  and in this method we define ***mobilityhelper***.

I was wondering if I can use mobilityhelper in another program. 
For example, I wrote another program and in my program I import WIFISegment, then define wifi = WIFISegment() and I can use its method "add" as follow *wifi.add(h1)* (h1 is host here).

**My question is How I can use mobilityhelper of add() method in my other program. Because I need to set a new mobility each time.**

Thanks
Farzaneh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way is to return it:

```
return tb, mobilityhelper
```

and use it like this:

```
original_ret_value, your_mobilityhelper = wifi.add(h1)
```

But that would break compatibility with your old code (`add` returned `TBIntf`, but now it returns tuple). You could add optional parameter to indicate whether the `add` method should return mobilityhelper or not:

```
def add( self, node, port=None, intfName=None, mode=None, return_mobilityhelper=False ):
    ...
    if return_mobilityhelper:
        return tb, mobilityhelper
    else:
        return tb
```

Now if you use `add` the same way you did before, it behaves the same way it did before `wifi.add(h1)`. But you can use the new parameter and then get your mobilityhelper

```
whatever, mobilityhelper = wifi.add(h1, return_mobilityhelper=True)
```

or

```
returned_tuple = wifi.add(h1, return_mobilityhelper=True)
mobilityhelper = returned_tuple[1]
```

---

The other way is to modify a parameter (a list)

```
def add( self, node, port=None, intfName=None, mode=None, out_mobilityhelper=None):
    ...
    if hasattr(out_mobilityhelper, "append"):  
        out_mobilityhelper.append(mobilityhelper)
    return tb
```

It's still compatible with your old code but you can pass a list to the parameter and then extract your mobilityhelper

```
mobhelp_list = []
wifi.add(h1, out_mobilityhelper=mobhelp_list)
mobilityhelper = mobhelp_list[0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It could help me a lot. Because of the limited space of the comment I ask the second part of my question here, as using mobility in ns3 is a little bit different than defining mobhelp_list = [].

Comment: @user226876  Well, you did confused me a little bit :D  Both ways I suggested are for getting the `ns.mobility.MobilityHelper` object you created in `add` method. But maybe you wanted to provide premade mobilityhelper to the `add` method in the first place (create the mobilityhelper in your other program and pass it to `add` method as argument)?

Answer (score 1):

The mobilityhelper is defining as below in class WIFISegment add method (as mentioned in the last question) :

```
        mobilityhelper = ns.mobility.MobilityHelper()

        # Install mobility object to the ns-3 node.
        mobilityhelper.Install( node.nsNode )
```

and it installs on each host (node.nsNode) when we use wifi.add().

Now in my other program I want to use this mobilityhelper, but install a new type of mobility such as below:

```
      mobilityhelper.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::GridPositionAllocator",
                             "MinX", ns.core.DoubleValue(0.0),
                             "MinY", ns.core.DoubleValue(0.0),
                             "DeltaX", ns.core.DoubleValue(130.0),
                             "DeltaY", ns.core.DoubleValue(100.0),
                             "GridWidth", ns.core.UintegerValue(2),
                             "LayoutType", ns.core.StringValue("RowFirst"))

     mobilityhelper.SetMobilityModel("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel")


        # Install mobility object to the ns-3 node.
        mobilityhelper.Install( h1 )
```

Now was wondering how I can use that mobility in my new program and install a new mobility for my node.

I hope I don't make you confuse.